# No license in package.json

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I cloned a project from (...) / I am working on a node project.

When I run my code with the yarn I do the following command:

```
yarn start
```

However, it shows:

```
yarn run v1.22.10

warning ..\package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have tried uninstalling, removing, and updating yarn and npm, but I still have the same error.

I also tried to manually update `package.json` but I still have the same error.

Comment: And do you think your `package.json` *does* contain a license field and a start script? Please give a [mre].

Comment: to start a new node project from scrach you could use npm init. (It works also if you use yarn)
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-init

Answer (score 3):

If `package.json` in the root folder of your project contains "license" field and you're still getting this warning. That means there is another `package.json` that is this warning for.

As you can see the path of the JSON file is in the warning:

```
warning ..\package.json: No license field
```

That double dots `..\` saying that the `package.json` file is one folder up where you are running your command. It could be **OUTSIDE** the project folder you're working on.

So if you go one folder up you will find another `package.json` file. Either add "license" field into it or simply delete the file if you do not need it.