# Error when trying to run yarn start - package.json: No license field error Command "start" not found

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, tailwind-css, package.json

So I am currently working on an Instagram clone (watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDgEqoQUBgk). I am trying to run `yarn start`, however I get these error messages. I added the errors and my `package.json` code below. Is there anything you guys recommend I do? I tried so many "solutions" but nothing is working (I have both node and yarn installed I verified by checking the version).

The error:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

My package.json folder

```json
    {
      "name": "instagram",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "react-scripts:start": "sleep 5 && react-scripts start",
        "react-scripts:dist": "react-scripts build",
        "start": "run-p watch:css react-scripts:start",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your `scripts` section is missing a `watch:css` entry, which should be a command that generates your CSS using Tailwind. For an example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61968222/how-do-i-start-react-app-with-tailwind-watch

Comment: It could be this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72371413/8730140